# Do all modal formulae classify digraphs?

Tags: graph-theory, modal-logic

I know that some modal formulae do classify digraphs. For example, $\Box \phi \rightarrow \Diamond \phi$ classifies all *serial* digraphs, i.e. digraphs such that for all vertices $v_i,$ there exists some $v_j$ such that there is an arrow from $v_i$ to $v_j$.

Is it the case that every modal formulae defines such a class, perhaps trivially small or large, of digraphs? And given an arbitrary digraph, is there a modal formula that classifies it?

Comment: The answer to the first question depends whether you are interested in 'interesting' classes of directed graphs, or not. Trivially, a given modal formula $\varphi$ defines the following class of of pointed models $M_s$ (digraphs with the valuation and a designated evaluation state): $\{M_s \mid M_s \models \varphi\}$.

Comment: As for the second question, the answer is 'no'. (I assume that by the fact that a formula classifies a digraph, you mean that the formula holds only in the corresponding model). One reason (but not the only one) for this is that formulas of modal logic cannot distinguish bisimilar models. A classic result in modal logic is that bisimilar models satisfy the same modal formulas (but not vice-versa). So, for a given arbitrary model, we can construct a bisimilar model that will satisfy the same set of modal formulas.

Comment: Also, regarding the second question, we can construct a formula describing a given model (up to bisimilarity) only if the model in question is finite (I assume the standard modal logic). So, if you are given an infinite model, the best you can hope for is a formula that provides only a finitary approximation of the model's structure.

Comment: If you are interested in what properties of models (and hence digraphs) are definable by formulas of modal logic, I would recommend looking at the corresponding chapter (2.6) of _Modal Logic_ by Blackburn, de Rijke, and Venema

Comment: @CharlesBronson Thank you for the detailed answers! I'm an MA student doing research in formal semantics (from a linguistics perspective); are you aware of any introductory texts on Modal Logic that would be a good fit for me?

Comment: @m-lekk I'm not sure about modal logic from the linguistics perspective, but here is a couple of suggestions. A very nice and accessible textbook\overview, which I often suggest to my students as a great intro to the topic, is _Modal Logic for Open Minds_ by Johan van Benthem. A more technical and comprehensive textbook that will last you a long time is _Modal Logic_ aka **THE BLUE BIBLE** by Patrick Blackburn, Maarten de Rijke, and Yde Venema